# How to control electron.js app?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm new to electron.js.I created a game using html,css and javascript. Right now the app is running offline on the client side.

But i want to access,analyse and change that app.One way this can be possible is to load game resources from a server,so i can have complete access and control over app.But i don't want to put heavy duty on server.

Basically i want app's resources loaded from the user's computer,also i want to control app.The electron.js app should be able to work offline also.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ["electron online"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-online) npm plugin to check app is connected to internet or not. If app has internet access you can perform your action to send updates to serer otherwise you can store those actions in ["electron-json-storage"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-json-storage) and later when have internet connectivity may be on app launch or at any specific event you can send those local storage information to server.

Comment: Thanks for answering.I just want to know whether i can change data in the electron app.

Comment: I am not getting your point. Can you please explain it bit more or may be can share an example which data you want to change in the electron app.